# How to interpret the output produced by summaryRprof?

Tags: r, memory-management, memory-profiling

I'm using Rprof to analyze peak memory usage for a function I've written. I have no idea how to interpret the output. This is what I'm looking at:

```
index: "my.function":"function.cpp"
     vsize.small  max.vsize.small      vsize.large  max.vsize.large            nodes        max.nodes     duplications 
            2874           497252            12537          2168970           285941         49467712                0 
tot.duplications          samples 
               0              173
```

All I know is that these numbers are in bytes and that 173 samples were taken over the function's runtime. Please help! I'm a researcher, not a programmer and I have no idea where to even begin.